# How do I secure an interview with another company during the day, when I have no vacation time at my current job?

Tags: interviewing, performance-reviews, vacation

I've seen this slightly answered [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5963/how-should-i-ask-for-time-off-to-attend-an-interview) but I the circumstances are different. I'm not a part time college student, but a full time employee of three years.

I don't have any vacation time left for the year, I have 10 sick/vacation days in total this year, and what I haven't used is earmarked for my honeymoon. I will already go my vacation days, and I will be taking unpaid time for the trip. (2 days off for house emergencies, the trip will be a total of 10 days, leaving 2 unpaid).

My boss has already told me that it looks bad that I'm taking unpaid time, and any additional unpaid time will go against my performance review. The rationale being, I was given X number of days, and if I can't manage to stay inside of that, then I'm unreliable.

The honeymoon is in a couple of months, but I'm currently looking at jobs now. If I have to take a day off, it could be paid, but it will add to the total number of unpaid days I end up taking.

My fear is I interview, and for some reason I'm not a fit for the new company, I'm digging myself into a hole at the job I currently have.

I also am opposed to lying to a current employer, so I don't want to fabricate reasons for taking time off.

Thanks,

edit: So this is all pretty legit advice, I'm hard pressed to pick a right answer, since they're all useful.

Comment: I'll just say that I think you're making the right choice looking for a new job. I struggle with 10 days of vacation and 10 of sick leave. 10 days of total PTO for the year is ridiculous!

Comment: I would suggest against telling your employer that you need time off to interview for another job.  So you might want to become okay with lying a little.

Comment: @DavidK This thing was the last straw, my boss told me "Well, you should have negotiated for more when you started", gee thanks. I had 6(Sick/Vaca) days for the first two years, it's a serious struggle.

Comment: @DaveJohnson I planned on saying something like "I need this day off for personal reasons", which is essentially true. However, I know it 'goes against' my review.

Comment: Is there any chance you could work extra hours on other days to make up for taking some time off to have an interview? That would be my suggestion.

Comment: @JBKing That's actually not too bad of an idea. My previous boss at this same job was very helpful in that regard. It won't hurt to ask.

Comment: This is highly opinionated so it's a comment - it appears as though you've already decided to leave? You've obviously got responsibilities outside work so you're essentially going to have to decide how much your responsibilities (and, it appears, health and future happiness) weigh up against the possibility of losing your job or getting no pay-rises/being made to have a crap time at work. This is a decision only you can make because - based on this comment I'm obviously biased...

Comment: @Ben I took this job because it's a non-profit. The exchange of lower pay was for laxer working conditions, and being closer to an area I want to live in. Only about 1/2 of that has come true, so, I've definitely decided to leave.

Comment: If you decided to leave, why you care the review?

Comment: @Mark Totally understandable question. I'm afraid of getting let go prematurely. But, in the end, maybe it's not the worst thing. I have a suspicion it's harder to get a job when you're unemployed. If I'm "unreliable" then it'll behoove the budget to let me go. I think they're always pretty cost conscious around here.

Comment: I think an immediately available candidate will have double advantage against another with 1 month notice.

Comment: @Mark I know at one point rather recently, there was a stigma against the unemployed. Basically, it's "Why were they let go?". Also, having a job I think gives me the confidence to negotiate a little, since I'm not paranoid about the consequences of staying unemployed.

Comment: the simplest way is you call in "sick" that day

Comment: this is horrible. so this is the most advanced country iín the world? in EU we have 4 weeks paid vacation, but most companies offer 5 or 6. In addition to any days you are sick (if approved by doctor)

Comment: @Rigolletto Funny you resurrect this 2 year old question with this comment. I'm now facing a crunch of having to get 2 surgeries within a year. I'll probably do one this year, and one next year. It's going to burn all my vacation time. I'm pretty unhappy about it.

Comment: @kevingreen I am sorry about that and I wish you luck. I might have to to have an operation as well, that will take 2 weeks. I am from a post-communist country and from youth we were indoctrinaded how great WEST and USA is, but lately, I see a lot of CONS as well and am gratefull for our socialist way of life in EU. (compared to USA)

Comment: @Rigolletto There's good and bad in the US. The health system is an issue. I know I can take all the time I need, and not get fired. I will also be paid for medical needed time off, even if it's months or years. Just not a full paycheck. Vacation time gets used first, then you go into a "short term disability" payments. For the last few years I've had medical problems that have eaten up my vacation. I'm starting to feel the drag.

Comment: Related / maybe duplicate - [Job interview during working hours, vacation not approved](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59596/job-interview-during-working-hours-vacation-not-approved)

Comment: @Dukeling I'd say that one is a duplicate of this one. I asked this question almost 2 years earlier. I'm still stuck at the same company. I can't believe I've been job hunting for almost 3 years.

Comment: If you are using your real name, then consider using an alias. This site is searchable...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are essentially in a Catch 22: You need to get a new job, but any time you take will ultimately result in having to take time unpaid.

You have limited options:

- Set up the interview and deal with the possibility of losing pay (not like you care if it looks bad, you're leaving)
- Try to get an interview really early or really late, giving yourself enough time to get from one place to the other without being late to the interview (again, I would be more interested in keeping the prospective employer happy than the current one)
- Try to set up a remote video interview that you can do on your lunch hour; this obviously works best if you work close to home
- Wait until you get more vacation time to start the job search

In any situation, you are likely to make things a little worse at your current place of employment, so tread carefully.  It does not sound like you want to get fired.  Best case scenario:  You start a new job before your honeymoon.  It is not always ideal to have to take two weeks vacation right after starting a position, but most reasonable employers will understand that something like a honeymoon was clearly booked far in advance.  Just make sure that the prospective employer is made aware of it before accepting any potential offer.

As a side note, any employer that tells you having to take time off looks bad is probably not someone anyone wants to work for.

Comment: No more vacation time until 2015, I'm not going to wait that long. 

How bad is it to ask the new employer to work around my schedule at all?

Comment: So long as you are professional about it, it rarely hurts to ask.  The questions that arise from your request will likely come up during the HR phone screen when they ask why you want to leave the company.  It is possible they will decline the request.  If you can financially afford to have a few days unpaid, I would go ahead and take the time unpaid to get out of that situation, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: The money isn't an issue, I'd just hate to get laid off or fired. My reasons for leaving are, it's not a software development company, and that's the track I'm really trying to get into. I got into more detail, but that's the gist. (I talked with a recruiter already about one position).

Comment: @kevingreen - Can you adjust your schedule so you leave work earlier in the day?  I start work at 6:30 in the morning and work until 3:00 in the afternoon.

Comment: @Ramhound This is a tactic I might use. Similarly to making up time, as was suggested. E.G work 6 hours one day, 10 the next to recoup.

Comment: If you havea something like a honeymoon that can;t be moved planned at teh time you are job hunting, make sure to tell them during teh negotiation and ask if you can have the time off. Never wait on this until you are at the new job.

Answer (score 5):

> My fear is I interview, and for some reason I'm not a fit for the new
>   company, I'm digging myself into a hole at the job I currently have.

You should never plan on just interviewing with one company.  If you're serious about leaving (and I personally think you should be; 10 days of combined sick/holiday time after 3 years is ridiculous) then you need to *get* serious about leaving.  You interview with as many as you need to, until you find one that is a good fit.

> My boss has already told me that it looks bad that I'm taking unpaid
>   time, and any additional unpaid time will go against my performance
>   review.

If you're serious about leaving, then what does a note in a performance review matter?  It doesn't.  And I suspect your boss is probably concerned that you may already have been using those days of unpaid leave to seek other employment, which is why he's discouraging you from taking any more.  Some might consider that to be unethical behavior on the part of your employer.

Anyways, in addition to the suggestions made by Chris and Dave with respect to interviewing remotely or by phone, early or late in the day, and trying to schedule as many interviews together as possible (which are very good ideas), there is a possible alternative.  You could cancel your request for paid leave during your honeymoon.  That would free up several paid leave days, which you could use for interviews.  Stick with the suggestions to line up multiple interviews, and schedule them for the same day or block of days.  Do your interviews, being sure to either note that you need leave to cover your honeymoon or to arrange a start-date that is after your honeymoon.

Then in the best-case scenario you don't upset your employer by exceeding your allocated number of paid leave days and you get paid leave to cover your honeymoon from your new employer (and probably some awkward questions about why you're cancelling the leave request).  In the more likely scenario you don't upset your employer by exceeding your allocated number of paid leave days and you take your honeymoon as unpaid time.  And in the worst-case scenario (if none of the interviews work out) you'd have to take your honeymoon as unpaid leave with your current employer, and deal with whatever fallout comes from that.  Which might not be fun, but you could use it to point out that it's their substandard allocation of personal days that made the unpaid leave necessary.

> I also am opposed to lying to a current employer, so I don't want to
>   fabricate reasons for taking time off.

How do you feel about telling the truth creatively?  It's not terribly inaccurate to describe a job interview as "an important errand that I can't do at any other time".  Or "a pressing obligation that just came up".  Or "something that I need to do for my own health and well-being".

As an aside:

> The rationale being, I was given X number of days, and if I can't
>   manage to stay inside of that, then I'm unreliable.

That rationale is absurd.  If they give you 10 days to cover *both* vacation and sick leave, then their reasoning implies that they either expect you to never get sick or to not take vacations, because that's essentially the only way to stay within such a paltry limit.

Comment: I've got several resume's out there, this is just me getting advice preemptively. There's no way I'm not going over my paid vaca days, that's already happening just because of the trip. But, extra days are the tricky part. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Like aroth says, just say; "sorry for the short notice, I have to take a day off for personal reasons. No, I do not want to discuss the reason." The boss will probably guess you have an embarrassing medical reason or a family emergency. Let him guess. Just say you can't discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

> My fear is I interview, and for some reason I'm not a fit for the new
>   company, I'm digging myself into a hole at the job I currently have.

Well... your fear is completely justified.

Seems like you have a few hard decisions ahead of you.  One path would be to try and schedule a few interviews for the same day; trying to get 2 or 3 in a row then take a sick day gambling that one of those jobs would hire you.

Of course, there is another problem here: most companies don't grant vacation time within the first 6 months of employment.  So even if you do get a job offer how do you propose to handle that with your upcoming wedding?

In other words, you are in a pickle no matter what you do.  If you look and don't get a job then you are further behind.  If you look and get the job then you'll have to try and negotiate some up front vacation time that a lot of companies won't agree to.

What I'd do in this situation is wait until after my honeymoon then start the job search.  It will be far easier to "fake" an emergency requiring me to not be at work after the fact than it will before hand.  Never mind the fact that you are already going through a stressful time getting married.  No need to pile on additional stress.

Comment: I'm in a tech field, interviews have lasted 4 hours to a full day, but I'm definitely open to scheduling them together. As for the honeymoon thing, I'd make it clear in the interview that's something I'm doing, I'd aim to make my start date after. I plan on negotiating vacation this time, make sure I end up better off. The trip is in 6 weeks, sooner than I realized a moment ago. But I think that's enough lead time for an interview, me giving a notice, and taking the trip, then starting soon enough. (I hope)

Comment: It's easy enough to say at the interview "my honeymoon is {dates}, I'm happy to take unpaid leave". I've seen similar things and it's never been a problem. Most people understand that wedding schedules are fixed.

Comment: Most companies will be accommodating about vacation time in the first 6 months of employment if you are open and up-front about your needs.  Just say "I have pre-existing travel plans on <dates>, I trust that won't be an issue".  If the company is really interested in hiring you this will not put them off.  Usually they'll let you take the time as paid leave borrowed against your future leave accrual.

Comment: @aroth: When I've worked for someone else I always negotiate the vacation time as well.  However, I've seen places that refuse to depending on the size of the company and the job level you are trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Usually companies where you apply for the job will not see negatively if you say you need an early or late interview. Taking the current duties seriously, even when looking for a new job, is a positive feature, a feature of employee they would like to have. Also, not all jobs allow just to take a vacation for a day, some require to take a weak at once at least, for instance. Pretending to be sick is probably the most unethical thing to do so also cannot be a requirement. And simply walking out of the office without telling anything may cost the current job immediately in some cases.

Plan carefully the journey from your work location to the place of interview, taking the earliest possible time to leave, and tell the new potential employer you can only arrive at this time. A company that absolutely requires candidates to come in the middle of the working day will never get best people. A serious boss can stay an hour late to interview the job candidates. Serious bosses tend to sit for a while in the evening anyway.