# As an intern, do I tell my boss I am going to interviews?

Tags: interviewing, united-states, internship

I am currently interning at a small company, so I answer directly to the CEO himself. I started at the beginning of the year and the role was said to be for a few months at least, though we did not discuss formally how long it would be. I did specify at the outset that I would be later looking for a permanent graduate role and this was acknowledged.

Now, in the coming weeks I have some interviews coming up during work hours,   so will need to ask for a few hours off on someday, maybe multiple times a week. I am wondering whether I need to advise my boss that I am going to interviews? Because I am still getting a steady flow I presume they are under the assumption that I will remain for a while. My question is do I need to tell my boss I am going for several interviews in the coming weeks?

Edit: I would say my relationship with my boss is fine, but pretty much purely formal. We rarely have off-topic conversations, majority of interactions are work focused.

Comment: What is the relationship like with your boss?

Comment: [How should I ask for time off to attend an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/5963)

Comment: If you're looking for a permanent role in your current company, you could just try having a discussion with your manager about that (how to do that might make for a decent second question).

Comment: An open-ended internship sounds odd to me, how does it differ from a job?

Comment: Is it a paid or unpaid internship?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich The employer gets to pay less (generally).

Answer (score 3):

This situation strikes me as different from most "how do I handle asking for time off from my current job to interview" questions, because a) it's an internship, which is typically limited in scope and timeframe, and b) the current employer has not given you specifics about how long they expected you to stay.

Under most circumstances, I would not discuss interviews with a current employer. But, based on the above, I would discuss your plans with the CEO. Tell him you're planning for your future and give him some insight into the specific path you're hoping to follow in terms of career growth. Let him know you enjoy working for his company (assuming that is true) and you'd be interested in a permanent internal position but you're also planning on using PTO to look elsewhere.

By doing so, you really have nothing to lose. If he's a reasonable person with good intentions and he likes your work, he'll want to support you no matter what. If he responds positively and has an opening for you, great! You just talked yourself into a job at a company you already know and trust. If he doesn't have room, he'll understand your plans and support your future. On the other hand, if he's unreasonable, doesn't like you, etc. - then no harm done, you're already looking elsewhere and good riddance.

Regardless, it sounds like you're doing the right thing by looking. Lots of internships turn into permanent positions, but in other employers, the "internship" is just a way to get some cheap temporary labor. I think it's generally understood that internships are temporary either way, so it should not surprise anyone for you to be job searching.

Answer (score 1):

Here was my strategy when I interned for UPS. I asked about different positions at the company to my direct manager, talked to my initial HR representative, **and** looked outside the company.

At the end of the day, although it would be ideal for you to continue with your current company (depends on the circumstances) **know** that they are not ***obligated*** to give you anything at the end of the contract period. If they offer you something, that's great. But if they don't, you are left holding an empty bag.

Be proactive.

As far as time off, this may conflict with your regularly scheduled hours. However, by telling them the reason, you can signal to them that you are serious about securing continued employment. If they don't act first and offer you something, they will lose you.

Answer (score 1):

You have absolutely zero obligation to tell them you're interviewing. If you need time off, simply request it for "personal reasons", or some other non-specific purpose.