# Getting time off for job interview

Tags: interviewing, new-job, time-off

I've just read the following answer:
- [How should I ask for time off to attend an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5963/how-should-i-ask-for-time-off-to-attend-an-interview)

But have posted a new question anyway as I believe my situation is a little different.

So I found out I will most likely be losing my job in a couple months, unless I make significant improvements in my performance. I don't believe I'm capable of reaching the level my current employer requires in such a short period of time, so I'm looking for new jobs.

I have been offered a job interview 7 days from now. I have asked if they can manage an interview before / after normal working hours and I'm waiting for them to reply.

But in the event that I have to attend the interview in the middle of the daytime, how should I proceed about getting time off?

I have two days holiday remaining this year. I would prefer to book a day's holiday, but I'm supposed to give two weeks notice.

Should I just say to my boss that I need a day's holiday for 'personal reasons'? Or should I just avoid booking a day off altogether and simply tell my boss that I have some kind of appointment and that I'm unable to work that day / morning?

It is also a little awkward with it being such a small office and my boss sits right near me.. So I imagine I'd have to do it by email in case he asks for more information on why I need to get a day's holiday last minute.

**EDIT:**

*Just to clarify (based on some feedback on my question), it was my boss who told me that I needed to improve in order to keep my job (rather than rumours).
Also I don't plan to lie and say I have a doctors appointment, but was considering saying a 'personal appointment' or 'personal reasons' etc.*

Comment: Your question doesn't seem any different from the linked post. The top-voted answer is also basically the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have an appointment to go to for personal reasons. You can say 'doctor appointment' but then you run the risk of them asking for a doctor note which you won't be able to provide and that can get you in a jam. People have to go do stuff all the time, you don't need to give your life story. People around you are probably doing this right now.

Comment: Or just call in sick that day? If you are back the next they are unlikely to ask for a doctor's note.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say how you found out you will be losing your job - were there some rumours (which may be totally untrue) or did your manager or HR or someone else who would know tell you officially?

In the first case you would first make sure that this is actually true. Often people make assumptions that turn out to be wrong.

In the second case, any manager who is not completely blind will know that you will be looking for a new job, and that you will have to go to job interviews. That's the normal and expected thing to happen. You won't be waiting until the last day.

So you say that you will take some time off for "some personal business". There are two possibilities then. Either your manager figures out that you are most likely going to an interview and will let you go, because he or she is a decent person and doesn't want you to end up without any job when you leave the company. Then everything is fine. Or your manager figures out that you are most likely going to an interview and doesn't allow you to go, because he is power mad, doesn't give a damn about the employees, and enjoys being an ass. In that case it's not so fine, but you must go to interviews, so you go anyway.

(That's why you must make sure that this expected job loss is for real. If that job loss is just based on rumours then your manager might be totally unaware of it and might not know you need to go to interviews. And just leaving for interviews puts your job in danger - fine if you are losing your job anyway, not so fine if you acted on rumours only).

Comment: Good point considering the aspect that the eminant lay-off could be a rumour - that adds a new context to the OP's situation where he needs to get clarification on that matter before acting too hasty.. +1

Answer (score 0):

First, don't lie to your boss by telling him that you have:

- a doctors appointment
- you need to attend to a funeral
- that your dog needs to to see a vet
- or anything similar..

A lie is not just a personal burden for anyone with at least a bit of conscience, it might also eventually be revealed. Besides that, your boss might do the math after finding out that you will resign and can conclude what that off-day was for anyway.

Second, it's completely reasonable to not disclose the full reason behind you needing a day off. What I find personally acceptable is something along those lines:

> *"Hi boss! I'm aware that I should give 2 weeks notice before taking a day off, but due to personal reasons I would like to ask you if you can make an exception this time - I would really appreciate it!"*

In case your boss digs further, you could simply reply:

> *"Due to the fact that this matter is not just personal but also really important to me, I can't disclose any further information and I would appreciate if you can understand my situation."*

Try not to be too harsh or insisting, instead try to be friendly and come across as contempt about your request to take a day off on short notice.

Since interviews normally (depending on the location and company) don't take a whole day, you could also try to be diplomatic and ask for an unpaid half-day off and offer your boss to make up for those 4-5 hours by working overtime on other days. Best of luck and let us know how it went if you like..

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, so I have no idea why it would have been downvoted.

Comment: @gnasher729 People seem to have different opinions about their relation to bosses or honesty in general, I could only guess.. ;)